# How to force reach-router (in Gatsby) to reload the page when going to currently active route again?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, reach-router

I have a situation similar to the following:

```
<Link to="products" state={{ category: "all" }}>All Products</Link>
<Link to="products" state={{ category: "lawnmowers" }}>Lawnmowers</Link>
<Link to="products" state={{ category: "saddles" }}>Saddles</Link>
```

The idea is that depending on which link the users clicks, I'd filter out the products to only show that category. I'm reasonably satisfied with the ease of use of this solution and ideally wouldn't want to change it.

This works fine when I'm on a different route, e.g. I'm in `/about` and click the lawnmowers link, I'll get a page full of lawnmowers. However, if I'm on the `/products` route, clicking any other link that also leads to `/products` itself simply does nothing. The site doesn't refresh, the state doesn't change and Gatsby or Reach seem to be blocking this somehow.

Is there any way to circumvent or disable this behavior and somehow force Gatsby to reload/rerender the page?

Comment: Why do you want to reload the page? That's kind of shitty for the user. Maybe instead style links to the current page differently so the user knows what's happening and doesn't click on them?

Answer (score 1):

React rerenders the page when props or state change.

> if I'm on the /products route, clicking any other link that also leads to /products itself simply does nothing

This implies that neither props nor state change because you're on the same route?! Then you will not get a rerender. If I'm mistaken please rephrase and be more specific with your question.

One possible solution: By clicking the link you also trigger a function that changes the state. This means, you would have to move away from the concise <Link ... /> and instead implement a whole lot of state management code. But there is no way around if you filter by changing state.

Use [React hooks](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks) useState for changing state and useEffect for applying the state change. Use Reach Router's [`navigate`](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks) to trigger the state change.